# Derivation of variance-reduced gradient estimate

Tags: numerical-methods, machine-learning, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

In [this paper by Ilyas et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.08598.pdf), there is this variance-reduced gradient estimate
$$\nabla \mathbb{E}[F(\theta)] \approx \frac{1}{\sigma n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\delta_{i} F(\theta + \sigma \delta_{i})$$
for $\delta \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$. Specifically, this is in the case of antithetic sampling, where $\delta_{j} = -\delta_{n-j+1}$ (as a means of reducing variance in the gradient estimate). I am trying to rederive this approximation.

From what I can tell, this estimate is probably derived via finite-difference, so we have something like
$$\nabla \mathbb{E}[F(\theta)] \approx \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{F(\theta + \sigma \delta_{i}) - F(\theta)}{\sigma \delta_{i}},$$
and with antithetic sampling resulting in sign changes, the $F(\theta)$ terms cancel each other out.

But the math doesn't quite work out, and I can't tell how to pull $\delta_{i}$ up into the numerator (since it is not necessarily a unit vector). I have looked up terms like "finite-order gradient estimate" or "gradient estimation techniques" and have only been able to find recent research which builds upon results such as this one, and so I can't help but feel like this derivation has since been passed in to tribal knowledge.

How do you derive this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's simpler than you think. It's a simple thing, just confusing notation.

For background:\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{\theta\sim\pi(\theta|x)}\left[ F(\theta) \right]
&=
\int F(\theta)\pi(\theta|x) \,\text{d}\theta \tag{1} \\
\nabla_x
\mathbb{E}_{\theta\sim\pi(\theta|x)}\left[ F(\theta) \right]
&= 
\mathbb{E}_{\theta\sim\pi(\theta|x)}\left[ F(\theta)\nabla_x\log \pi(\theta|x)
 \right] \tag{2}
\end{align}
using the reinforce log-derivative trick. Note that $\delta\sim\mathcal{N}(0,I)$, which is not expected to be affected by the antithetical sampling (though in a theoretical sense it may be). Since $\theta = x +\sigma\delta$, we have that $\pi(\theta|x) = \mathcal{N}(x,\sigma^2 I)$, so 
\begin{align}
 \log \pi(\theta|x) 
&= -\frac{k}{2}\log(2\pi) + \log\det(\sigma^2 I)^{-1/2} -\frac{1}{2}(\theta - x)^T\sigma^{-2}(\theta-x) \\
\nabla_x \log \pi(\theta|x) &= -\frac{\sigma^{-2}}{2} \nabla_x\sum_i (\theta_i - x_i)^2 \\ &= {\sigma^{-2}} (\theta - x) = \sigma^{-1}\delta
\end{align}
Nice. Now, we use a Monte Carlo approximation on equation (2), with $n$ samples. This is where some horrible notation is coming into play. While before they were considering a fixed (deterministic) $x$ and a random variable $\theta = x + \sigma\delta$, now they are considering a fixed single $\theta$ value (instead of just calling it $x$).
I will try to rewrite it to make it clearer (mostly for myself).
$$
\mathbb{E}_{\theta\sim\pi(\theta|x)}\left[ F(\theta)\nabla_x\log \pi(\theta|x)
 \right] \approx 
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n F(\theta_j) \sigma^{-1}\delta_j 
= \frac{1}{n \sigma}\sum_{j=1}^n F(x + \sigma\delta_j)  \delta_j 
$$
where $j$ indexes the samples $\theta_j = x + \delta_j\sigma$. This makes much more sense (in their notation, they simply renamed $x$ to $\theta$). Notice that in equation (2) we are *integrating out* the $\theta$ variable (i.e., marginalizing over it, or taking the expectation over it), so *it should not appear in the final output*.

PS: regarding finite difference, it is actually designed to replace the finite differencing, which is infeasible in high dimensions - hence the use of this cheaper randomized natural evolutionary strategies approach instead.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand why they used antithetic sampling. Maybe it works better empirically, but as you said it shouldn't make a difference for $\delta \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$ and it doesn't make a difference in the second-order finite difference step that they put in the algorithm.

Comment: @Richard Yeah I'm not sure about the antithetic sampling. My guess is that it preserves some form of symmetry (kind of like some ML models sample batches in a way that balances categories/labels), which is helpful for balanced gradient estimation.